# How do I turn off the display (DPMS) without X?

Tags: xorg, display, console, backlight

I've been trying to switch off the built-in screen of a device I've got, but I can't seem to completely control it without X running.

If I run a GUI (I've tried Kubuntu 12.10) and issue the command `xset dpms force off`, the screen goes black, including the backlight. If I run a console OS (12.04 LTS), the screen blanks as expected after a few minutes of inactivity, but the backlight stays on dimly. I've tried using `setterm` to manipulate the powersaving mode (`setterm -powersave powerdown`, as well as a couple of variations), but there is a very faint glow from the backlight when the screen blanks in this way. The same happens if I use the sysfs interface, which does have a control method for the backlight (it just doesn't switch it off completely).

I've looked at the `xset` source and discovered that it sends an internal "opcode" seemingly called `DPMSForceLevel` to the X server. At this point, I got a bit lost and ran out of time. I intend to have another go at following the source, but I'd love it if anyone can offer any insight!

**Background**

The device is an O2 Joggler. It's an Intel Atom based device with what I'm led to believe is a Sharp touchscreen and an Intel GMA500 GPU). I was hoping not to have to run X, so if I can send the screen hardware the correct commands without, I'd be happy.

I am aware of *vbetool*, which is supposed to offer this sort of control of display hardware, but unfortunately, I tried it and got nowhere (`Error: something went wrong performing real mode interrupt`).

Comment: I was just about to recommend you `vbetool`, which unlike `setterm` does work here on this old EeePC, also an Atom CPU. – Did you find a solution already?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't. I've tried several other things, including writing a small C program to send an ioctl to the framebuffer graphics interface but I've had no luck.